# dbms_output.put_line not working for type variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am working on oracle 11g and am new to the PLSQL part of oracle.
I've trying out a program that has to give the output as 'King' but for some reason the dbms_output.put_line does not seem to work for a type variable. I tried checking it out with a normal user number variable just in case to see if the difference and it seems to be working fine for it.

Thank you for the help.

[image: This is how the query looks inside PLSQL but when executed normally gives an output]

Comment: If you could share the test case you mentioned where it worked for a number, that would help narrow down the issue. Also please post text not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

Before running the anonymous block to tell the SQL/Plus client that you expect it to output the console.

Comment: Note that SET SERVEROUTPUT ON is a SQL Plus command, and as such it is not terminated by semicolon. SQL Plus will tolerate it, it will silently ignore the semicolon, but keeping a clear distinction between what is a client command and what is sent to the db server is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

MT0 gave you the answer: run the SQL Plus command `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before you run the procedure.

You should understand a few things from this.

First, the issue has nothing to do with the data type of your variable; it would apply equally well if you didn't have any variables and the entire body of your procedure was simply to print the hard-coded string `'Hello World'`.

Second, the important point that `put_line` writes the "output" to a memory buffer - not directly to the screen. What you do with the data from the buffer is no longer PL/SQL, it's a function of (a task for) your client software, SQL Plus in your case. `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` is a SQL Plus command, which instructs SQL Plus to read the data from the buffer and display it on the screen.

Answer (score -1):

You should use command as below:

```
set server output on ;
```

After that you will see output .

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and the accepted one? No need to post the same answer twice